# Jquery Drag and Drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

$(document).ready(function() {

```
            $("#dvv").mousedown(function() {

                $("#dvv").mousemove(function(e) {

                    $("#dvv").css({ 'margin-top': e.pageY - 15, 'margin-left': e.pageX - 15 });

                });

            });

<div id="dvv" style="background-color: Blue; width: 150px; height: 150px; margin: 250px 550px;
        cursor: move;">
        test Div
    </div>
```

Div Click nonstop drag help me

Comment: "Div Click nonstop drag help me" best question evar.

Comment: You have no hope of getting an answer to such a vague question. Be detailed.

Comment: Make Drag And Drop 
I do not know English

Comment: Geez, give him a break. He doesn't speak english. He wants to know how to manually create drag and drop functionality.

Comment: What is your language?  Try asking in that.

Comment: If you speak in spanish, I might be able to help.

Comment: A shame that this was closed. He obviously speaks little English, and yet posted code that made his intention clearer than that of many here who speak English; except they don't get their question closed. Instead of helping out a little, people mocked and (originally) down-voted him. Now his question is closed altogether. What a shame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please note:** I've never tried to implement this before, but this seems like a start.

Please note that I removed the margins from your div, and added absolute positioning, so it is not the original element you started with.

Hopefully this will give you something to work with.

**UPDATE:** Just changed it a bit. Now, using offset(coordinates) instead of css, it works regardless of margin settings, and absolute positioning doesn't need to be set.

```
<div id="dvv" style="background-color: Blue; width: 150px; height: 150px; margin: 0; cursor: move;">
test Div
</div>

$("#dvv").mousemove(function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('moving')) {
        $(this).offset({ 'top': (e.pageY - $(this).data('offsety')), 'left': (e.pageX - $(this).data('offsetx')) });
    }
});

$("#dvv").mousedown(function(event) {
    $(this).data('offsetx', (event.pageX - $(this).offset().left) );
    $(this).data('offsety', (event.pageY - $(this).offset().top) );
    $(this).addClass('moving')

});

$("#dvv").mouseup(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('moving')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQueryUI.  It has a "[draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable)" and a "[droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable)" component that will get you going with plenty of examples.

Comment: I want to make myself ready I do not want